# Magento 2: New order email totals/subtotal decimal places

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates, order-email

we have changed our site to display prices in 4 decimal places using [this extension](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal)

However on the new order email we would like to trim off the extra zeros. This is how it is displaying...

Subtotal £15.2500

Shipping & Handling £7.5000

Tax £4.5500

Grand Total £27.3000

I think these are being added to the email via this

**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/totals.phtml**

```
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
<?php if ($_total->getBlockName()): ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml($_total->getBlockName(), false); ?>
<?php else:?>
<tr class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_code?>">
    <th <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLabelProperties()?> scope="row">
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?></strong>
        <?php else:?>
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>
        <?php endif?>
    </th>
    <td <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValueProperties()?> data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_total->getLabel());?>">
        <?php if ($_total->getStrong()):?>
        <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatValue($_total) ?></strong>
        <?php else:?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatValue($_total) ?>
        <?php endif?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif?>
```

Which is controlled (I think) by this...

**vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php**

Can we format the totals here?

Thanks

Comment: yes, you can but first override file.

Comment: which one? and how to format it? thanks

Comment: toDecimal() - try with this function